# What is the purpose of these comments in Babel output?

Tags: javascript

Babel transpilation output follows. What is the purpose of generated comments like `/*#__PURE__*/`?

```js
function foo() {
    return (<div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
    </div>)
}
```

transpiles to:

```js
"use strict";

function foo() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", null), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", null));
}
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5632, https://github.com/Andarist/babel-plugin-annotate-pure-calls, https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/08/27/7.0.0#pure-annotation-support? It's apparently for Uglify *et al.*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was [introduced in Babel 7](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/08/27/7.0.0#pure-annotation-support):

> ...transpiled ES6 classes are annotated with a `/*#__PURE__*/` comment
> that allows gives a hint to minifiers like `Uglify` and `babel-minify`
> for dead code elimination. These annotations are added to other helper
> functions as well.

This annotation tells those tools that, although the function is immediately invoked, it's *side-effect free* and can be eliminated if its return value is unused. As explained in [the original issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5632):

> Minifiers like Uglify try to remove dead code from minified builds. To
> completely remove a declaration, they have to prove that it is
> side-effect free. Unfortunately in JS this is often not possible as
> pretty much anything can have arbitrary effects.
>
> An important issue is that ES5 emit for class can't easily be
> determined to be side-effect free. As a result, tree-shaking is
> ineffective. ...
>
> A very simple solution could be to have a hint for the minifier,
> inside a special comment. If the emit added a `/*#__PURE__*/` comment
> at the beginning of ES5 classes it could easily be detected and
> removed by Uglify.

Likewise the React element creation can be eliminated if that element doesn't get used anywhere; it has no side effects.

Comment: Is this saying it is deterministic code (same output for the same inputs) which helps eliminate dead code?

Comment: @jcalfee314 it tells us that, although the function is immediately invoked, it has no _side effects_. So if the return value isn't used, it can safely be eliminated. See [the original issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/5632) that led to the inclusion of this comment in Babel's output.