# How does arguments of React.createElement() function is executed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const COMP = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>IN COMP</h1>
      {console.log("in comp")}
    </>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <COMP />
      <h1>IN APP</h1>
      {console.log("in app")}
    </>
  );
};
```

I was expecting to first console "hello" then "in app". Because what BABEL compiler does to above code is:

```
const Comp = () => {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(/*#__PURE__*/React.Fragment, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, "IN COMP"), console.log("in comp"));
}

const App = () => {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(/*#__PURE__*/React.Fragment, null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, "IN APP"), /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Comp, null), console.log("in app"));
}
```

Expecting output on console:
in comp
in app

But got unexpected output on console:
in app
in comp

1. Does react suspends execution of child components and first executes all other {js code} ?
   I want to know how actually does React executes this piece of code...
2. What is the meaning of /*#**PURE***/ ? Aren't children passed as in form of list then ?

Comment: The simple answer is that `React.createElement(Comp, null)` doesn't actually *call* `Comp`.  It ultimately calls this function which just creates an object literal: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/facebook/react@43eb28339a0dc645c27b36f06200da63d57c292f/-/blob/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js?L149-161

Comment: Note that asking 2 questions at the same time makes it impossible to write a good answer for people who only know the answer to one of them. Also the answers might become very large and harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`React.createElement()`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactElement.js#L362)
does not suspend the execution of child components.
The functions are executed "in one go", but recursively:

- First `App` is executed (aka. "rendered") and creates React elements of all its child React components,
- *then* all the created child React elements are rendered, and
- then the child elements of the child elements are rendered,
- ... and so on.

#### The `React.createElement()` return value

Each argument *(some of them)* passed to `React.createElement()` is
itself a React element created by `React.createElement()`.

E.g. the `React.createElement()` of `App` creates an object like:

```
{
    "$$typeof": Symbol("react.element")
    props: Object {  }
    type: function Comp()
    name: "Comp"
    ...
}
```

You can see that `Comp` is still a function, i.e. it was not executed yet.

#### The execution order

Here I re-wrote your `App()` to illustrate the execution order:

```
const App = () => {
    return React.createElement(   // step 2: call `createElement()` with elements created in step 1
        React.Fragment,
        null,
        React.createElement("h1", null, "IN APP"),  // step 1: Get element to be rendered
        React.createElement(Comp, null),            // step 1: Get element to be rendered
        console.log("in app")                       // step 1: console log
    );
};
```

#### A simple illustration using plain javascript

This nested and recursive execution of functions might be confusing.
Here I tried to write some simple plain javascript code with an equivalent execution order:

```
const render = function( type ){
    const element = type();
    if( typeof element === 'function' ){
        render( element );
    } else {
        console.log( 'render:', element );
    }
};

const create = function( type ){
    return type;    // of course, React does more than this ;)
};

const child = function(){
    return create( 'leaf', console.log('child') );
}

const root = function(){
    return create( child, console.log('parent') );
}

render( root );
```

*(It confuses me too, so forgive me if I made mistakes, but feel free to comment)*

#### The `/*#__PURE__*/` annotations

See:

- [What is the purpose of these comments in Babel output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61909829/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-comments-in-babel-output)
- https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/6209